# How to know if an active directory object's attribute is modifiable or not using LDAP schema?

Tags: c++, windows, azure-active-directory, active-directory, ldap

I am trying to identify if an attribute of an object is modifiable or not using LDAP c++.

So far I have tried to query the schema object and tried to find some correlation between systemFlags and modifiable attribute.

But I am unable to understand one hard and fast property of an attribute in schema which can tell us if an attribute is modifiable or not.

For example even administrator cannot modify few attributes which are important for AD integrity, but I am looking for a way to identify those attributes before hand programatically so that I wouldn't even attempt to touch them.

OR is there any other way to identify those, which I am missing.

Comment: It doesn’t have to be in the schema. A given user may not have enough permission to modify some things.

Comment: Yes, for example even administrator cannot modify few attributes which are important for AD integrity, but I am looking for a way to identify those attributes before hand programatically so that I wouldn't even attempt to touch them.

Comment: Well you can't identify them all, but you can certainly identify all operational attributes from the schema, and I suspect also structural attributes or whatever they're called, e.g. the `objectClass` entries, and everything that contributes to the DN. But in general you're tilting at windmillls. That's not what the schema is for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted by [user207421](https://stackoverflow.com/users/207421/user207421) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77678154/how-to-know-if-an-active-directory-objects-attribute-is-modifiable-or-not-using#comment136944684_77678154), speaking about LDAP in general:

- a user's ability to modify an attribute is not just determined by the attribute's schema definition. It also depends on the [permissions assigned to the user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/fundamentals/users-default-permissions). Even an administrator might be restricted from modifying certain attributes crucial for AD integrity.
- some attributes are operational or structural by nature, such as those contributing to the `Distinguished Name (DN)` or `objectClass`. These are often not modifiable, but this property might not be explicitly stated in the schema.
- the schema can tell you if an attribute is generally read-only or system-only, but it may not provide all information about non-modifiable attributes, especially those governed by permissions or their intrinsic nature.

And when it comes to Azure AD (or is it "[Microsoft Entra ID](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/security/business/identity-access/microsoft-entra-id) now?), I do not see any obvious Entra ID-specific feature which would facilitate the identification of modifiable attributes.

So, to programmatically identify non-modifiable attributes, you would need to:

- query the schema for flags like `systemFlags` and `searchFlags` to identify attributes typically non-modifiable.
- implement a function to check the current user's permissions on an attribute. That might involve attempting a 'dry run' modification or querying permission-specific attributes if available.
- develop a list of known operational and structural attributes which are typically non-modifiable (like those forming the DN).

> But I am looking for a way to identify those attributes before hand programatically so that I wouldn't even attempt to touch them.

... since it is challenging to identify all non-modifiable attributes in advance, I would still recommend designing your application to handle modification exceptions gracefully.
Meaning: catching errors related to modification attempts and handling them appropriately.

```cpp
try {
    // Attempt to modify an attribute
    modifyAttribute(ld, attributeName, newValue);
} catch (const LDAPModificationException& e) {
    // Handle the exception if modification is not allowed
    std::cerr << "Modification not allowed: " << e.what() << std::endl;
}
```

---

> Also is there any better way known to you for checking the user permission? It’s better to directly try to modify the desired value rathen than attempting to dry run, since if it’s gonna fail it’s gonna fail.

So your preference is for directly attempting to modify an attribute rather than performing a dry run to check permissions.

Instead of checking permissions beforehand, directly attempt to modify the attribute. If the user does not have the necessary permissions, the LDAP server will return an error indicating the failure. That means implementing robust error handling to catch and appropriately respond to modification errors. That includes distinguishing between different types of errors, such as permission issues, network errors, and other LDAP-specific errors.

If possible, design these modification attempts to have minimal impact. For example, if you are checking if an attribute can be modified, you might attempt to set it to its *current* value. That way, even if the modification succeeds, it does not actually change the attribute's value.

A pseudocode for this approach could be:

```cpp
#include <ldap.h> // Include LDAP library

// Function to try modifying an attribute
bool tryModifyAttribute(LDAP* ld, const std::string& dn, const std::string& attributeName, const std::string& value) {
    LDAPMod mod;
    char* vals[2];
    vals[0] = const_cast<char*>(value.c_str());
    vals[1] = nullptr;

    mod.mod_op = LDAP_MOD_REPLACE;
    mod.mod_type = const_cast<char*>(attributeName.c_str());
    mod.mod_vals.modv_strvals = vals;

    LDAPMod* mods[] = {&mod, nullptr};

    // Attempt to modify the attribute
    int rc = ldap_modify_ext_s(ld, dn.c_str(), mods, nullptr, nullptr);
    if (rc == LDAP_SUCCESS) {
        // Modification successful
        return true;
    } else if (rc == LDAP_INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS) {
        // Insufficient permissions
        return false;
    } else {
        // Other LDAP error
        // Handle appropriately
    }

    return false;
}

// Usage example
LDAP* ld; // Assume this is an initialized LDAP connection
std::string dn = "cn=John Doe,ou=users,dc=example,dc=com";
std::string attributeName = "description";
std::string currentValue = "Current Description";

bool canModify = tryModifyAttribute(ld, dn, attributeName, currentValue);
```

`ldap_modify_ext_s` is used to modify the attribute. It checks the return code to determine if the modification was successful, failed due to insufficient permissions, or failed due to another reason.

That works when checking permissions independently is not feasible or when the schema does not provide sufficient information.

Comment: How’s Microsoft be able to identify the modifiable attributes which they show in UI, is there any particular query or a fixed list for modifyiable attributes depending upon object class?

Comment: Also is there any better way known to you for checking the user permission? It’s better to directly try to modify the desired value rathen than Attempting to dry run, since if it’s gonna fail it’s gonna fail.

Comment: @VivankSharma "... show in UI?": Not sure: Microsoft, having designed Active Directory, likely has predefined knowledge about certain attributes of different object classes. That information goes beyond what is available in the schema and includes understanding of the operational and structural nature of attributes. Plus, the UI might dynamically check the permissions of the logged-in user against each attribute to determine if it should be enabled for modification. That would involve real-time queries to assess whether the user has the necessary rights to modify each attribute.

Comment: @VivankSharma "It’s better to directly try to modify the desired value rathen than Attempting to dry run, since if it’s gonna fail it’s gonna fail." True. I have edited the answer to illustrate that approach.

Comment: I was talking about LDAP in general. I made no reference to any specific product. Don’t put words into my mouth please.

Comment: @user207421 Thank you for that feedback, and apologies for having misrepresented your comments. I have edited the answer to clarify that.